# How can I make a caricature like a Who Was book in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My son wants to make a series of fake Who Was book with him and his friends on the covers. If you've never seen one, it's a whole series about famous people, with a caricature on the cover, like this:

[image: Who was Nelson Mandela]

Could anyone suggest a good technique for taking a photograph of a person and cartoonifying it in just this way?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Probably because your question is very broad. Most likely that cover was hand drawn, at least to a high extent. What have you looked at trying? Also, that's an incredibly detailed cover for a side project fake book series

Answer (score 1):

I would start by taking your pictures with a white background that would be easily removed (and won't get distorted when you warp the photo). Than take the photo into photoshop and extract the person from the background and use the `Filter->Liquify` tool to shape their faces however you'd like.